# Regex for a python string that does not start or end with specific characters

Tags: python, regex

I need to process input strings that cannot have `*` in the middle, but if it does start or end with `*`, it needs to start with `*.` or end with `.*` (cannot have both, max of one `*` allowed)

I have the first part of checking if it has `*` in the middle, but how do I add on that if it starts or ends with just `*` without the `.` it is also invalid.

```
import re

def invalid_syntax(str):
    regex_str = '(?<!^)\*(?!$)'
    if re.search(regex_str, str):
        return True
    return False
```

It should behave as follows:

```
invalid_syntax('exampleStr') == False
invalid_syntax('*.exampleStr') == False
invalid_syntax('*exampleStr') == True
invalid_syntax('examp*leStr') == True
invalid_syntax('ex*ampleStr') == True
invalid_syntax('exampleStr*') == True
invalid_syntax('*.exampleStr*') == True
invalid_syntax('*.exampleStr.*') == True
invalid_syntax('exampleStr.*') == False
```

Comment: Check the first and last character of the string via index then once you weed out those cases, the regex would be trivial right?

Answer (score 2):

If regexes prove to be a struggle, consider using standard string operations instead.  That may result in code that more closely corresponds to the problem statement and be easier to understand/maintain:

```
def test(s):
    """ I need to process input strings that cannot have * in the
        middle, but if it does start or end with *, it needs to start
        with *. or end with .* (cannot have both, max of one * allowed)
    """
    c = s.count('*')
    return c == 0 or c == 1 and (s.startswith('*') or s.endswith('*'))
```

Here is a test run:

```
>>> for s in ['*okay', 'okay*', 'okay', 'not*okay', '*']:
...     print(test(s), repr(s), sep='\t')
True    '*okay'
True    'okay*'
True    'okay'
False   'not*okay'
True    '*'
```

Note, the problem specification is not 100% clear about whether a single `*` is allowed.  Possibly this should be rejected because it both starts with and ends with a star.  To add this requirement, just add `and len(s) != 1`.

Comment: This 100% of the time. I don't doubt that the regex pattern in one of the other answer(s) is correct, but anyone can understand this code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want one regex you can try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GyMhPD/2)):

```
^[^*]*$|^\*\.[^*]*$|^[^*]+\.\*$
```

- `^[^*]*$` -> match if string doesn't contain `*`

or:

- `^\*\.[^*]*$` -> match if string begins with `*.` and doesn't contain additional `*`

or:

- `^[^*]+\.\*$` -> match if string ends with `.*` and doesn't contain additional `*`